# Close button not showing in FancyBox 1.3.4

Tags: button, fancybox

I am using this piece of code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox(
        '<h2>Welcome!</h2><p> We are growing, so invite your friends!</p>',
        {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'showCloseButton'   : true,
            'width'             : 350,
            'height'            : 'auto',
            'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
            'centerOnScroll'    : 'true',
            'transitionOut'     : 'elastic'

        }
    );
});
</script>
```

For some reason, the close button is not appearing. What is going wrong?

Comment: Check the sample. Is the problem there as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that the "`fancybox.png`" file (which contains the fancybox sprite images) is located in the same directory than the fancybox css file. If the problem is with IE only, then check [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/8530478044b9f586)

Comment: Hm, don't know how I missed checking the file location! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me not shown when the popup is opened as layer, but works when opened as iframe.

Try this in your CSS:

```
#fancybox-close {
    display:inline !important;
}
```

Worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

I searched online for ages because no close button or any of the attributes of fancybox was showing. Only to realise three things after experimenting with the chrome developer tool (F12) that two things caused this:

1) the fancybox files where put into a sub folder causing the URL not matching so i just took out the fancybox folder from a sub folder called JS which i put it in and just left it in the main root folder

2) on the css make sure its not url:(blahblah) its just url(blahblah) meaning no ":"

3)putting it with just url(fancybox_sprite.png) for example works without adding the full path because the full path didn't work for some weird reason

I hope this helps someone!